# Dictating spelled numbers in English and other languages

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

Is there a way to have iOS voice dictation spell out numbers?  I mean speaking  145 and having it write "one hundred forty five"; this would be useful in English and other languages. Although it’s not that common to spell out numbers in English, in my experience it seems a lot more common in foreign languages such as Italian and German.  It’s really difficult to spell out the very long words in those languages and so this would be a gr8 feature

I’ve done a lot of searching and tried different things  but nothing seems to work, including here on stack exchange  where almost everything on this topic is several years old.  In fact some of the posts I read indicate that there was the reverse problem years ago  that was solved by saying “numeral”  beforehand  to avoid spelling the number.

Update (March 2023): recently, I accidentally found that  numbers will be spelled out when you say something like "lessons (or exercises) two through nine", but this only seems to work with numbers less than 10

Edit:
In response to @MeanAverageMeanie I installed GBoard and tried dictating "eleven plus fourteen equals twentyfive" in Italian, German, and English. Unfortunately, it still produced numerals rather than spelled words in each case, as seen below using Gboard within the iOS Mail app:
[image]

Comment: I guess sometimes we have to accept that some things are not possible...
By the way, "numeral" still work, and can make you able to write "2" instead of "to" if you have a simple number.

Comment: @AncAinu Perhaps by "not possible" you mean "not possible anymore"? If so, I'm ready to agree. Just kind of funny to have a situation where you can say, "Well, iOS used to be able to do that, but lost the ability after upgrades..."

Comment: When I was a technical writer (1984-1986), it was a standard rule to spell out numbers ten and below.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have iOS voice dictation spell out numbers?

Unfortunately, the built-in dictation feature on iPhone does not currently support the automatic conversion of numbers into their corresponding written-out form. As you noticed, when dictating, it will typically transcribe numbers as digits rather than words.

---

However, there are some third-party dictation software options available that may offer this feature, such as [Dragon Anywhere](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dragon-anywhere/id1023486580), [Evernote](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/evernote-notes-organizer/id281796108) or [Dictate + Connect Lite](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dictate-connect-lite/id305873261). It's important to note that, while some of these apps may have more advanced features, their accuracy in transcribing numbers and words may vary depending on factors such as background noise, speaking speed, and accent, among others.

---

Note: Some of the proposed apps have a paid subscription service, so you will need to purchase a subscription to use the app beyond the free trial period.

Comment: The original question specified "iOS voice dictation".  Yes, I agree "iPhone does not currently support" this feature, but (as noted in a comment I made above) "iOS used to be able to do that" before downgrades

Answer (score -2):

The answer is to install Google’s GBoard keyboard. Its voice dictation feature automatically spells out numbers like “forty-five” rather than typing them out as “45”. I don’t know why iOS doesn’t do this. I’ve tried, but ultimately it was Google to the rescue. It also works in other languages, i.e. French “quarante-cinq” and Spanish "cuarenta y cinco”.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you suggested but it did not work for me. I've edited my original post to provide an image and further details. Can you provide an image and further details demonstrating what you see when you do the same test?